# How to Use Spatie PdfToText - Step by step

Tags: php, pdf

Listen, I'd like to use Spatie PdfToText to read content from a PDF file. I don't know much about docker, comoser and I don't use Lavaler but pure PHP.

1. Is it possible to do it somehow without the above?
2. How should I add this library step by step to my code to make it work?

I was relying on another pdf, but she had a problem with encoding some files sometimes and the web recommends this one. I've been rummaging for two days, but I can't find an answer that's clear for someone like me. I will be very grateful.

I program on windows, xamppie and sublime text, but I would like it to work also on Linux servers or clouds

Comment: You could have learned how to use Composer in less time than you've spent trying to figure out how to avoid using Composer. [That is your most reasonable path forward.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

Comment: I used composer according to a guide on the Internet, but I get errors, that something is still missing. I took to htdocs threw a folder with unpacked git zip. I entered this subfolder via CMD and entered composer update. I don't know what it does and I don't know how it works, but it came up like vendor / autoload.php and I tried like this: https://pastebin.com/8aY0xz6F
But i get:
https://pastebin.com/N839jAaQ

Comment: Some people wrote something on the Internet that it is not enough, I do not understand how to do it anymore and I have to understand it today and therefore I am asking for help step by step. It's not as easy for me as it is for you.

Comment: I would ask for your understanding and help seriously, because boasting about my knowledge and making fun of it will not help me learn anything. I have already searched simple solutions on the web. This is something complicated

Comment: I don't have much time to learn docker frameworks etc. I want to use it in a simple php script :(

Comment: System nie mo�e odnale�� okre�lonej �cie�ki.
 in F:\xampp\htdocs\pdf-to-text-main\src\Pdf.php:73 is in English: The system cannot find the path specified.
  in F: \ xampp \ htdocs \ pdf-to-text-main \ src \ Pdf.php: 73. do i need to install something?

Comment: If you don't want to use the library's recommended way to install things, that is of course your right, but the burden is on you now. Luckily, as you are a PHP developer, the processes isn't complicated, although it is repetitive. First, download and extract the package. Second, `require` all files (often just in `src` but that's not always true). Third, open `composer.json` and look in the `require` section for additional libraries and go off to GitHub, and repeat the previous steps, including the `composer.json` file.

Comment: KJ - but in this pleace i don't see any exe file for windows :( and what should I do if the script can land on a server with an unknown system for which I don't have ssh?

Comment: https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html - I found an exe here ready, I'll check if it works. But where should I put it and what should I do to make it compatible with other systems? This will land on I don't know what hosting and I don't know what system or cloud. Why is it so weirdly made?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JVFNwXm0 - works on windows, but now the question is what to do if it is to work on a server or a cloud with a system other than windows?